# Should people be more careful when running a Tor relay?

Tags: anonymity, security, relays

I've decided to run a Tor relay (not an exit node) for donating bandwidth to the Tor network.

I've modified very few lines of my torrc file, since I'm trying to learn more about the technology but know very little at the moment.

My question is: should I know more before running a Tor relay? Am I putting on risk the people that's passing through my node? Which reference should I read?

Here's my `/etc/tor/torrc` file:

```
Log debug file /var/log/tor/debug.log
Log notice syslog
DataDirectory /var/lib/tor
HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/hidden_service/
HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:80
ORPort 9798
Nickname ididnteditheconfig
AccountingMax 1 GB
AccountingStart day 12:00
ContactInfo giuscri giuscri@gmail.com
ExitPolicy reject *:* # no exits allowed
```

Answer (score 2):

Whowa, you probably do not want debug logging, and I would explicitly recommend against it as the logs may contain information that is considered sensitive.

If all you are doing is trying to run a relay, you like wise do not need HiddenServiceDir or HiddenServicePort.  An absolutely minimal config ([taken from the instructions](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-doc-relay.html.en#torrc)) would be:

```
ORPort 443
Exitpolicy reject *:*
Nickname ididntedittheconfig
ContactInfo human@...
```

It looks like you are trying to limit the capacity to 1 GiB/day, so add AccountingMax/AccountingStart as appropriate.

The [torrc manual](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en) has more details regarding all of the options.